# Show gridview inside the gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a project on recruitment system. In this project I have gridview which contains details like vacancy title, company name, dept name etc. Now what I want is, there should be hyperlink on vacancy title and when user clicks on vacancy title, it should show criteria for that vacancy in the another grid without refreshing that page. That means I have to maintain one grid inside another but I dont know how to achieve this.
Can any one guide me please???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar with the use of Colorbox plugin.

This works when you know the links will lead to grids that can be precompiled in the page when it loads.

If a popup window is allowed to show the grid, than this could be your option.

a) have a placeholder on your page to store the generated html code in
 you'll want unique identifiers for each of your links.

b) from code behind, i'm building the grid.

--snip--

```
Dim mystat As New TableCell With {.Text = "<a href='#' class='" & texttoappear & h & i & j & "'>" & mycount & "</a>", .HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center}
myrow.Cells.Add(mystat)
prepareminidataset(myoraclefilter.ToString, (texttoappear & h & i & j).ToString)
```

---snip--

The anchor leads to the same page , more important is the class i'm building as this is the class used by the colorbox plugin to find which grid it needs to show.
Prepareminidataset is a function in which i'm retrieving the details from the database backend (you might not need this). The unique combination  **texttoappear & h & i & j**  becomes the "**reference**" string used later on in my functions. (h,i & j are my positions in the grid, so each field is unique)

c)  I) I'm then building the datagrid to show via a function, using the fetched data from the database as the dataset ds

```
Private Sub prepareminigrid(ByVal reference As String, ByRef myds As DataSet)
    Dim Itemheader As Control = LoadControl("warrantydetailgrid.ascx")
    Dim thegrid As GridView = CType(Itemheader.FindControl("mygrid"), GridView)
    thegrid.DataSource = myds
    thegrid.DataBind()
    myhiddenpopups.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<div id='" & reference & "' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'> "))
    myhiddenpopups.Controls.Add(Itemheader)
    myhiddenpopups.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</div>"))

    If Not strScript.ToString.Contains("$('." & reference & "').colorbox({width:'50%', inline:true, href:'#" & reference & "'});") Then
        strScript.AppendLine("$('." & reference & "').colorbox({width:'50%', inline:true, href:'#" & reference & "'});")
    End If

End Sub
```

II) *myhiddenpopups* is my placeholder on the aspx page where i'm adding the html code in (so colorbox can retrieve it when i'm pressing the anchor

III) finally, strscript is a startupscript the will add the different colorbox functions with their unique tag (=reference) to the startup javascript.

So what does it look like?
This is the build up grid with the anchor tags
[image]

This is the grid that shows when a user clicks a link
[image]

on the main.aspx page, you need the placeholder, which data won't be shown

[image]

The result from the compiled page, when the 'prepareminigrid' has ran for each of the anchors it needs to create;

[image]

You can see the unique DIV id's for each of the anchors (this is what the colorbox function will look for in the inlin html code) and the tables below

The drawback is that your preloaded data needs to be relatively small. If you've got a table with hundreds of lines, the loading time of your page will increase and eventualy the user will get a 'a script is taking a long time to complete ' warning message.

hope it helps

K

Answer (score 0):

Dear Friend i have use the gridview inside the data list so from the same way you can use the 
grid view inside the gridview. Here the code sample

The .aspx Code

```
  <asp:DataList ID="dl_College" runat="server" OnItemCommand="dl_College_ItemCommand"
               OnItemDataBound="dl_College_ItemDataBound">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <fieldset>


                       <asp:GridView ID="grdCorse" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="text12_d"
                           Width="100%">
                           <HeaderStyle BackColor="#244e7e" ForeColor="#f7f7f7" />
                           <RowStyle CssClass="gridview-row" />
                           <Columns>
                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stream Name">
                                   <HeaderStyle CssClass="grdsize" />
                                   <ItemStyle Width="42%" />
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                       <span class="text12_d">
                                           <%#Eval("StreamName")%>
                                       </span>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Seats">
                                   <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                       <%#Eval("StreamSeats")%>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Duration">
                                   <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                       <%#Eval("StreamDuration")%>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fee">
                                   <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="15%" />
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                       <asp:Label ID="lblStreamFee" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("StreamFees")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                       <asp:ImageButton ID="imgLock" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# String.Format("{0}{1}","Login.aspx?ClgId=" , Eval("CollegeId")) %>'
                                           CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="~/images/Lock.png" Width="30" Height="20" />
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mode">
                                   <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                       <%#Eval("StreamMode")%>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                           </Columns>
                       </asp:GridView>
                   </fieldset>
                   <br />
                   <asp:Panel ID="pnlCollegeRank" runat="server">
                       <fieldset>
                           <legend class="Legend_Header"><strong>College Rank</strong></legend>
                           <asp:Panel ID="pnlImage" runat="server" Visible="false">
                               <table width="100%">
                                   <tr>
                                       <td style="width: 100%;" class="Main_StripCollegeRank">
                                           To check college rank, please login
                                       </td>
                                       <td style="float: right; background-color: #3b5998;">
                                           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgLock" PostBackUrl='<%# String.Format("{0}{1}","Login.aspx?Collegeid=" , Eval("CollegeId")) %>'
                                               CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="~/images/Lock.png" runat="server" />
                                       </td>
                                   </tr>
                               </table>
                           </asp:Panel>
                           <asp:Panel ID="pnlRank" runat="server" Visible="false">
                               <span style="float: left; padding-left: 6px; width: auto">
                                   <asp:GridView ID="grdCollegeRank" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="text12_d"
                                       Width="">
                                       <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" />
                                       <RowStyle CssClass="gridview-row" />
                                       <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#fffbfd" />
                                       <Columns>
                                           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                                               <HeaderTemplate>
                                                   <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                       <tr style="background-color: #244e7e">
                                                           <td style="width: 100%; background-color: #244e7e; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;
                                                               color: white; padding-left: 3px" colspan="2" align="left">
                                                               College Rank in
                                                               <asp:Label ID="lblYear" runat="server" Text="2011" ForeColor="white" Font-Size="13px"
                                                                   Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                                           </td>
                                                       </tr>
                                                       <tr>
                                                           <td style="width: auto; color: #244e7e; text-align: left;" class="grid_HeaderRank">
                                                               Source
                                                           </td>
                                                           <td style="width: auto; color: #244e7e; text-align: right;" class="grid_HeaderRank">
                                                               Rank
                                                           </td>
                                                       </tr>
                                                   </table>
                                               </HeaderTemplate>
                                               <ItemTemplate>
                                                   <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                       <tr>
                                                           <td style="width: auto;" align="left" class="text12_d">
                                                               <asp:Label ID="lblSource" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SourceName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                           </td>
                                                           <td style="width: auto; text-align: right; padding-right: 16px" class="text12_d">
                                                               <asp:Label ID="lblRank" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("OverallRank")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                           </td>
                                                       </tr>
                                                   </table>
                                               </ItemTemplate>
                                           </asp:TemplateField>
                                       </Columns>
                                   </asp:GridView>
                               </span><span style="float: left; padding-left: 6px; width: auto">
                                   <asp:GridView ID="grdCollegeRank1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="text12_d"
                                       Width="">
                                       <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" />
                                       <RowStyle CssClass="gridview-row" />
                                       <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#fffbfd" />
                                       <Columns>
                                           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                                               <HeaderTemplate>
                                                   <table width="100%">
                                                       <tr style="background-color: #244e7e">
                                                           <td style="width: 100%; background-color: #244e7e; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;
                                                               color: white; padding-left: 3px" colspan="2" align="left">
                                                               College Rank in
                                                               <asp:Label ID="lblYear" runat="server" Text="2010" ForeColor="white" Font-Size="13px"
                                                                   Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                                           </td>
                                                       </tr>
                                                       <tr>
                                                           <td style="width: auto; color: #244e7e; text-align: left;" class="grid_HeaderRank">
                                                               Source
                                                           </td>
                                                           <td style="width: auto; color: #244e7e; text-align: right;" class="grid_HeaderRank">
                                                               Rank
                                                           </td>
                                                       </tr>
                                                   </table>
                                               </HeaderTemplate>
                                               <ItemTemplate>
                                                   <table width="100%">
                                                       <tr>
                                                           <td style="width: auto;" align="left" class="text12_d">
                                                               <asp:Label ID="lblSource" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SourceName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                           </td>
                                                           <td style="width: auto; text-align: right; padding-right: 16px" class="text12_d">
                                                               <asp:Label ID="lblRank" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("OverallRank")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                           </td>
                                                       </tr>
                                                   </table>
                                               </ItemTemplate>
                                           </asp:TemplateField>
                                       </Columns>
                                   </asp:GridView>
                               </span><span style="float: left; padding-left: 6px; width: auto">
                                   <asp:GridView ID="grdCollegeRank2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="text12_d"
                                       Width="">
                                       <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" />
                                       <RowStyle CssClass="gridview-row" />
                                       <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#fffbfd" />
                                       <Columns>
                                           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                                               <HeaderTemplate>
                                                   <table width="100%">
                                                       <tr style="background-color: #244e7e">
                                                           <td style="width: 100%; background-color: #244e7e; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;
                                                               color: white; padding-left: 3px" colspan="2" align="left">
                                                               College Rank in
                                                               <asp:Label ID="lblYear" runat="server" Text="2009" ForeColor="white" Font-Size="13px"
                                                                   Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                                           </td>
                                                       </tr>
                                                       <tr>
                                                           <td style="width: auto; color: #244e7e; text-align: left;" class="grid_HeaderRank">
                                                               Source
                                                           </td>
                                                           <td style="width: auto; color: #244e7e; text-align: right;" class="grid_HeaderRank">
                                                               Rank
                                                           </td>
                                                       </tr>
                                                   </table>
                                               </HeaderTemplate>
                                               <ItemTemplate>
                                                   <table width="100%">
                                                       <tr>
                                                           <td style="width: auto;" align="left" class="text12_d">
                                                               <asp:Label ID="lblSource" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SourceName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                           </td>
                                                           <td style="width: auto; text-align: right; padding-right: 16px" class="text12_d">
                                                               <asp:Label ID="lblRank" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("OverallRank")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                           </td>
                                                       </tr>
                                                   </table>
                                               </ItemTemplate>
                                           </asp:TemplateField>
                                       </Columns>
                                   </asp:GridView>
                               </span><span style="float: right; padding-right: 0px; width: 50%">
                                   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCollegeRank" CommandName="ViewMore" CausesValidation="false"
                                       runat="server" CssClass="ReadMore">View More...</asp:LinkButton>
                               </span>
                           </asp:Panel>
                       </fieldset>
                       <br />
                   </asp:Panel>
                   <fieldset>
                       <legend class="Legend_Header"><strong>Infrastructure</strong></legend>
                       <br />
                       <asp:GridView ID="grdHostelInformation" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                           CssClass="text12_d" Width="100%">
                           <HeaderStyle BackColor="#244e7e" ForeColor="#f7f7f7" />
                           <RowStyle CssClass="gridview-row" />
                           <Columns>
                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hostel">
                                   <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                                   <HeaderStyle CssClass="grdsize" />
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                       <a href="#" target="_blank" class="text12_d">
                                           <%#Eval("CollegeHostelInfo")%>
                                       </a>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location">
                                   <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                       <%#Eval("HostelLocation")%>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Internet">
                                   <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                       <%#Eval("HostelInteranet")%>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Laundry">
                                   <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                       <%#Eval("HostelLaundry")%>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Power Backup">
                                   <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                       <%#Eval("HostelElectricityBackup")%>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AC">
                                   <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                       <%#Eval("HostelAC")%>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Charges">
                                   <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                       <%#Eval("HostelCharges")%>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Occupancy">
                                   <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                       <%#Eval("HostelOccupacy")%>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                           </Columns>
                       </asp:GridView>
                   </fieldset>
                   <br />
                   <fieldset>
                       <legend class="Legend_Header"><strong>Contact Details</strong></legend>
                        <ul style="vertical-align:top; background-color:#f4faff;">
                            <li class="textLiExam">
                                <strong style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; color:Black;">Address &nbsp;:</strong>
                                <%# Eval("CollegeStreet")%>
                                <%# Eval("CollegeDistrict")%>
                                <%# Eval("StateName")%>
                                <%# Eval("CollegePinCode")%>
                            </li>
                            <li class="textLiExam">
                                <strong style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; color:Black;">Email Id &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;</strong>
                                <%# Eval("CollegePersonEmail")%>
                            </li>
                            <li class="textLiExam">
                                <strong style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; color:Black;">Website &nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;</strong>
                                <a href='<%# String.Format("{0}{1}","http://" , Eval("CollegeWebsite")) %>'
                                       target="_blank" class="textLiExam">
                                       <%# Eval("CollegeWebsite")%>
                                   </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="textLiExam">
                                <strong style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; color:Black;">Phone &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;</strong>
                                <%# Eval("CollegePhone1")%>
                                       ,&nbsp;
                                       <%# Eval("CollegePhone2")%>
                            </li>
                            <li class="textLiExam">
                                <strong style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; color:Black;">Fax &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;</strong>
                                <%# Eval("CollegeFax")%>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                   </fieldset>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:DataList>
```

Here The Code how to deduct the grid view in side the data list

```
  protected void dl_College_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {


        GridView grdCollegeRank = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("grdCollegeRank");
        GridView grdCollegeRank1 = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("grdCollegeRank1");
        GridView grdCollegeRank2 = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("grdCollegeRank2");
        Panel pnlRank = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlCollegeRank");
        string sqlquery1 = "select top 1 * from dbo.CollegeCourseStream,dbo.University where dbo.CollegeCourseStream.UniversityId = dbo.University.UniversityId and CollegeCourseStream.collegeId='" + Request.QueryString["Collegeid"] + "'";
        DataTable dt_Vendor1 = lk.dt_Select(sqlquery1);
        if (dt_Vendor1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lblAffiliation.Text = dt_Vendor1.Rows[0]["UniversityName"].ToString();            
        }

        DataSet sdr = new DataSet();
        sdr = ObjClsCollege.GetCollegeRank(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["CollegeId"]));
        grdRank = sdr.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        if (sdr.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            grdCollegeRank.DataSource = sdr.Tables[0];
            grdCollegeRank.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            grdCollegeRank.Visible = false;
        }
        string sqlquery2 = "select * from dbo.tblRankSource,dbo.tblRank where dbo.tblRank.SourceId=dbo.tblRankSource.SourceId and dbo.tblRank.CollegeId='" + Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Collegeid"].ToString()) + "' and tblRank.Year='"+ 2010 +"' order by Year DESC";
        DataSet sdr2 = lk.selectDate_Source(sqlquery2);
        grdRank1 = sdr2.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        if (sdr2.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            grdCollegeRank1.DataSource = sdr2.Tables[0];
            grdCollegeRank1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            grdCollegeRank1.Visible = false;
        }

        string sqlquery3 = "select * from dbo.tblRankSource,dbo.tblRank where dbo.tblRank.SourceId=dbo.tblRankSource.SourceId and dbo.tblRank.CollegeId='" + Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Collegeid"].ToString()) + "'and tblRank.Year='" + 2009 + "' order by Year DESC";
        DataSet sdr3 = lk.selectDate_Source(sqlquery3);
        grdRank2 = sdr3.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        if (sdr3.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            grdCollegeRank2.DataSource = sdr3.Tables[0];
            grdCollegeRank2.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            grdCollegeRank2.Visible = false;
        }

            if (Request.QueryString["CollegeId"] != null)
            {
                GridView currChk = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("grdCorse");
                ObjClsCollege = new ClsCollege();
                DS = new DataSet();
                ImageMap CollegeImage = (ImageMap)e.Item.FindControl("CollegeImage");

                string sqlquery = "Select * from College,State,Course where College.stateid=State.stateid and College.CourseId=Course.CourseId and  College.CollegeId='" + Request.QueryString["Collegeid"] + "'";
                DataTable dt_Vendor = lk.dt_Select(sqlquery);
                if (dt_Vendor.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    CollegeImage.ImageUrl = "College Image\\" + dt_Vendor.Rows[0]["CollegeImage"].ToString();
                    //CollegeImage.ImageUrl = dt_Vendor.Rows[0]["CollegeImage"].ToString();                    
                }
                DS = ObjClsCollege.GetTheCollegeCorse(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["CollegeId"]));
                if (DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    currChk.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
                    currChk.DataBind();

                }
                foreach (GridViewRow Row in currChk.Rows)
                {
                    Label lblStreamFee = ((Label)Row.FindControl("lblStreamFee"));
                    Image imgLock = ((Image)Row.FindControl("imgLock"));
                    lblStreamFee.Visible = true;
                    imgLock.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {


    }
```

so That you will find the gridview inside the datalist